# How to change the source of an <Image /> using an function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I use the `handleFavoritePress` to change the `<CardFeirasPopulares />` url?

- `FeirasPopulares` function:

```
import {View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import CardFeirasPopulares from '../../common/cards/popular/CardFeirasPopulares'
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { icons } from '../../../constants';

const FeirasPopulares = () => {

    const handleFavoritePress = () => {
       url = icons.favoritechecked
    }
    
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTitle} numberOfLines={1}>Feiras Recomendadas</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.showAll}>Mostrar Todos</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View>
                <FlatList 
                    data={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <CardFeirasPopulares 
                            nome={"Rua Tal"}
                            dias={['Seg', 'Qua']}
                            handleCardPress={handleCardPress}
                            handleFavoritePress={handleFavoritePress}
                            url={icons.favorite}
                        />
                    )}
                    horizontal
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item}
                    contentContainerStyle={{columnGap: 16}}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = {false}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

- `CardFeirasPopulares` code:

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import { icons } from "../../../../constants";

const CardFeirasPopulares = ({nome, dias, handleCardPress, handleFavoritePress, url}) => {

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.container}
            onPress={() => handleCardPress()}    
        >
            <View >
                <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{nome}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.cardSubtitle}>{dias[0]} - {dias[1]}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleFavoritePress()}>
                <Image 
                    source={url}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    style={styles.icon}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

I'm trying to change the CardFeirasPopulares url to another image when it's clicked, like if it's marked I dismark and if is dismark I mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useState` to control the image source.

Like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
// ...
const [url, setUrl] = useState(initUrl);
// ...
const handleCardPress = () => {
  setUrl(newUrl);
}
// ...
<Image source={url} />
```